# Is there a way to use box-shadow to have a round inset border?

Tags: html, css

I need an inner border for effect on these images. I have looked up how to do it and no tutorials are helping me. I have found one that looked right but doesn't seem to work.

I have applied this to a div, id, and even the image itself.

```
#img{
    box-shadow:
        inset 0 10px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Top */
        inset -10px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Right */
        inset 0 -10px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Bottom */
        inset 10px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Left */
        inset -7.5px 7.5px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Top Right */
        inset -7.5px -7.5px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Bottom Right */
        inset 7.5px -7.5px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Bottom Left */
        inset 7.5px 7.5px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5); /* Top Left */
    -moz-box-shadow:
        inset 0 10px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Top */
        inset -10px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Right */
        inset 0 -10px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Bottom */
        inset 10px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Left */
        inset -7.5px 7.5px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Top Right */
        inset -7.5px -7.5px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Bottom Right */
        inset 7.5px -7.5px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Bottom Left */
        inset 7.5px 7.5px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5); /* Top Left */
    -webkit-box-shadow:
        inset 0 10px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Top */
        inset -10px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Right */
        inset 0 -10px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Bottom */
        inset 10px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Left */
        inset -7.5px 7.5px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Top Right */
        inset -7.5px -7.5px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Bottom Right */
        inset 7.5px -7.5px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), /* Bottom Left */
        inset 7.5px 7.5px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5); /* Top Left */
}
```

It is supposed to be a full inset circle around the image. I am not even sure the pixel amount to use but I can't even get it to work to see what it is doing.
!(https://imgur.com/a/c5fTMJN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to make the image a background image of the div. First you have to remove the `<img>` from your html, then add this in the css and make sure that the class name is the same that you use in the html:

```
div .round-image {
      border-radius: 100%;
      background: url(2.jpg);
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px #ffffff96;
}
```

You could change the color code (the #....) to any transparent color if you wish, you can find rgba (transparent) color generators online or play around with the inspector tool's color picker and transparency picker in your browser.

My test looks like this, nevermind it's a rectangular image so it didn't become circular: https://gyazo.com/8e9c3deb54d5f784534c6d952a028400

Your div has to be square, same height and width, in order to become perfectly round with border-radius 100%.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to give us your description about html structure and all css associated. While you are giving your description of your html pages and css structure, you may find something wrong or improper way to prepare the static webpage.

This can be one of the applications of separation of concerns (SoC) in computer science. Try to divide your different  sections and describe it, the you shall find the problems.

This is the sample of work.

```
<body>
    <div class="roundedCorner">
    </div>
</body>

.roundedCorner
{
    width:350px;height:200px;
    border: solid 1px #555;
    background-color: #eed;
    box-shadow: 10px -10px 5px  rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px -10px 5px  rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px -10px 5px  rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -o-box-shadow: 10px -10px 5px  rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    border-radius:25px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that.
Here is the HTML:
 <div class="img" id="img">
    <img src="2.jpg" alt="Backpack" height="175px">
 </div>

And here is all the CSS related to this that I didn't include: 
.products img{
    justify-items: center;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

.img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

Comment: I guess your html code provided is self-explanatory

Comment: I'm sorry. I am new to this site. I am not sure how to add the code like you wanted.

Comment: At first not to use img as class or img. These nodes are default notes instead of customized label

Comment: Okay I changed the name to overlay and it still didn't work.